# How can I display a shortened text for the currently selected option in an AngularJS select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select. Some of the options in the select are very, very long, and the space for the select to sit in is quite short. For reasons of non-native select design hacks, I need the currently-selected option text to be shorter than the space the select element actually occupies.

I want the full text to be displayed when the element is active, e.g when all the options are displayed. Once an object is selected and the element is not active, I want a shorter text to be displayed.

I can do this by hiding the select and putting the shortened text into an element positioned absolutely over the select, but this brings up a world of cross-browser pain- hiding the select while allowing it to activate when clicked has EXTREMELY variable results across different platforms.

[Here's a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CdadUOjTID6hMMUTVJAC?p=preview) showing an example of this technique.

```
<div class="has-select">
  <select ng-model="activity" ng-options="c.name for c in options" ng-init="activity = options[0]">
  </select>
  <span class="short">
    {{ activity.name | limitTo: 30 }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Does anyone know a way to do this that would use only the standard select mark-up and not rely on additional elements?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems to achieving this:

- You can't use a smart "substring" function in Angular's ng-option since this will cause a rebind.
- Even if you have a logic triggered substring this won't affect the "dropdown" when it is active, seems like the browser (at least Chrome) is binding the data in the dropdown before ng-click happen, [badly written example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhOf3YgWykY0o3c4l0nN).

My recommendation would be to go with a "custom select" implementation similar to [FlatUI](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/) (but Angular style of course!). This will probably be the least painful way to achieve this.